# numpy multinomial function returns value error

Tags: python, numpy, multinomial

I am using the `numpy.random.multinomial(1,val)` [NumpyMultinomial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html), where val is a 1-D numpy array. The function gives the following error:

> ValueError('sum(pvals[:-1]) > 1.0',)

However, I checked the sum of the input array val using `val.sum()` and it sums exactly to 1. I don't know if the multinomial function has some bug. Can some one help me out with this. Alternatively, is there any other python module that I can use for sampling using multinomial distribution?

Comment: Could you post the contents of val?

Comment: It is probably due to rounding errors. Are you 100% sure on "it sums exactly to 1" and not maybe to `1.0000000000001` or so?

Comment: @seaotternerd thanks I did investigate the array and I found the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this strange behaviour is due to negative values in the array `val`. Actually I had a case where the `val` summed to 0.9999996, but it contained a negative element and due to this Multinomial function throws up the `ValueError`, which completely misleading of course because the sum never exceeded 1.